# Getting mean of 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a vector representation of n = 1000 images, where each image is represented as 2048 numbers.
So I have a numpy array with a shape of (1000, 2048) that I need to find the mean of in a 2048-d vector.
If I run this function:

```
def get_means(f_embeddings):
    means = []
    for embedding in f_embeddings:
        means.append(np.mean(embedding))
    return np.array(means)
```

I get an ndarray of shape (1000,). How do I loop loop over the array correctly to have a 2048-d vector of means from the original array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
np.mean(f_embeddings, axis=0)
```

which should do it without the loop.